# Handling tap on Pushpin in a fixed Map

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I have a Map control showing a few Pushpins. I do not want the user to navigate in the map so I disable it. But I do want the user to be able to tap on a Pushpin (and in the event I navigate to a detail page).

However when the Map.IsEnabled is false, the Pushpins don't seem to receive any gestures either. I've also tried using IsHitTestVisible, but with no luck.

Some code showing what I'm trying to do. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<maps:Map Name="Map"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed" LogoVisibility="Collapsed" ScaleVisibility="Collapsed" ZoomBarVisibility="Collapsed"
          IsEnabled="False">
    <maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TheCollection}">
        <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <maps:Pushpin Name="Pin" Location="{Binding Coordinate}" Content="{Binding Ix}">
                    <maps:Pushpin.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
                    </maps:Pushpin.Background>

                    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                        <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="PinTap"  />
                    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                </maps:Pushpin>
            </DataTemplate>
        </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </maps:MapItemsControl>
</maps:Map>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `IsEnabled` to `false` prevents the `Map` control from responding to user input, which affects the child `Pushpin` as you've seen. If you want the map to be read-only but the `Pushpin` to respond to gestures then I think you have two options:

1. Handle all the gesture events on the `Map` control and set `e.Handled` to `true`, which will prevent the `Map` itself from processing the event, but should leave the `PushPin` free to handle the tap gesture.
2. Create a `WriteableBitmap` of the `Map` and show that instead, and then display the `Pushpin` on top (NOTE: I suspect that the `Pushpin` control won't work outside of the `Map` control, so you'd need to create/re-template a control to look like a `Pushpin`).

UPDATE: The events that you need to handle on the `Map` to make it appear "read-only" but remain enabled are `MapPan` and `MapZoom`.

Comment: I'll try that. And, yes, the Pushpin works outside the map. I use it in an accompanying ListBox to have the same "look" of items in the list and in the map.

Comment: Any ideas on how to achieve "handle all gesture events". I've handled Manipulation[Started,Delta,Completed] and MouseLeftButton[Down,Up] and set e.Handled to true. Those does not help. Any more I should do something with?

Comment: `TouchPan`, `TouchRotate` and `TouchZoom` are the most likely candidates. You can see a full list of the events here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.map_events.aspx. To be honest, if you want a read-only map with an interactive layer on top, I think you're better off with the `WriteableBitmap` approach.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try those as well. Well, I'm thinking along those lines as well. But if I'm going to be doing a separate layer and using a transformation between GeoCoordinate to screen coordinates I can just go with IsEnabled="false" on the Map.

Comment: Nope. Those events are not available on WP7.

Answer (score 1):

So here's how I solved it after a lot of testing and browsing MSDN. It turns out that things are a bit different in the Map control on Windows Phone (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955762.aspx)). There are new behaviors and events compared to normal Silverlight.

```
<maps:Map Name="Map"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          CopyrightVisibility="Collapsed" LogoVisibility="Collapsed" ScaleVisibility="Collapsed" ZoomBarVisibility="Collapsed"
          MapZoom="Map_MapZoom" MapPan="Map_MapPan">
    <maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TheCollection}">
        <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <maps:Pushpin Name="Pin" Location="{Binding Coordinate}" Content="{Binding Ix}">
                    <maps:Pushpin.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
                    </maps:Pushpin.Background>

                    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                        <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="PinTap"  />
                    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                </maps:Pushpin>
            </DataTemplate>
        </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </maps:MapItemsControl>
</maps:Map>

...

private void Map_MapPan(object sender, MapDragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void Map_MapZoom(object sender, MapZoomEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: So, answering my own question seems a bit ego... but I didn't get all the way with Dereks suggestions. I know, I know, the solution is somewhere in the proximity of one of Dereks suggestions, but at the same time a bit vague. I'm not sure how to handle the mark answer here. It's my first question and I only got a semi-answer, how is this this normally looked upon here at SO? (no offense Derek - I appreciate the help) Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm glad you got to a solution to your problem in the end, which is what SO is all about. I'm fairly new myself, so I don't know what the normal approach is. From what I can tell though, you did solve the problem using the answer I gave: "1.Handle all the gesture events on the Map control and set e.Handled to true"; I just didn't quite indicate the exact events to handle. Personally, I'd like it if you accepted my answer (I'll update it with the right events), but I understand if you'd prefer not to.