# disable map movement from flicks

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I have a map on which I dynamically display pushpins, and would like to interact with the pushpins without interacting with the map (so I can't just disable the map by setting `IsEnabled="False"`, nor can I use an image of the map).

I've tried the techniques depicted here: [Handling tap on Pushpin in a fixed Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864243/handling-tap-on-pushpin-in-a-fixed-map), which work great for zooming, and panning.

Extending this idea I've set up event handlers for all the events that would seem to match:

```
   Hold="map_Hold"
   MapPan="map_MapPan"
   MapZoom="Map_MapZoom"
   ManipulationStarted="map_ManipulationStarted"
   ManipulationDelta="map_ManipulationDelta"
   ManipulationCompleted="map_ManipulationCompleted"
   MouseLeftButtonDown="map_MouseLeftButtonDown"
   MouseLeftButtonUp="map_MouseLeftButtonUp"
   TargetViewChanged="map_TargetViewChanged"
   ViewChangeStart="map_ViewChangeStart"
   ViewChangeEnd="map_ViewChangeEnd"
   ViewChangeOnFrame="map_ViewChangeOnFrame"
```

(in the event handlers I simply set `e.Handled = true;`)

Yet you can still pan the map by making flicking motions on it (like how you would flick to the next image in the photo app).

Is there a way to disable the map panning altogether?
Or is there a way to interact with the pins if `IsEnabled="False"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post was a while ago so you probably have solved the problem by now. But I had this problem today and this is the solution I had. (it's not very elegant, but seems to work fine).

For me this problem occurred when letting go of a pushpin after dragging and dropping it - Even though I had disabled the map_pan event when dragging a pushpin, the map would still move from the 'flick' gesture which is created when letting go of a push pin after dragging and dropping it.

First of all, create a page scoped DespatchTimer and an int which will be our counter:

```
    DispatcherTimer dti = new DispatcherTimer();
int counter =0;
```

Next, in the pushpin's MouseLeftButton up event, disabled your map, start the despatch timer with an interval of 1. Also create the Tick event handler for it.

```
 private void pushpin_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
Map.IsEnabled = false;
dti.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1); // 1 Seconds
        dti.Start();
        dti.Tick += new EventHandler(dti_Tick);
//other code logic
}
```

Next, create dti_Tick event. Within the tick event, stop the despatch timer when it is the second iteration into the tick event and re-enable the map. Reset the counter for future use.

```
 void dti_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter>= 1)
        {
            dti.Stop();
            Map.IsEnabled = true;
            counter= 0;
        }
    }
```

This process will have stopped any 'flick' from occuring after your drag and drop pushpin logic. Clearly this code can be further optimised, but hope it is of some help to you.